# how can i fix this?

Tags: browser, video, facebook, youtube

[image]
when i watch video in YouTube or Facebook or browsing, doesn't matter where, image is always like this. someone to have solutions about this? thank you!

Comment: Defective chip. Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: i don't know is defective, when i use old versions of Facebook or YouTube is work, but when i updates them, always show me like this. i think is a video driver or codec but im not so sure

Comment: Stock or custom rom? Which device?

Comment: stock android 4, asus padfone 2

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different version of the applications, and also use an up to date version of Android as that may help

Comment: only with very old version of the apps its work good, but sometimes also giving me those image,  special in youtube. im with last version of Android for my device which is android KitKat.

Comment: Perhaps install an app to check RAM usage